# NgRX Effect for downloading media file and dispatching progress Actions until Finish action is dispatched

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am learning NGRX and RXJS in my Podcast project.

My current question is: how to call progress Actions within my @effect based on my Download Action.

The effect looks like this and works:

```
@Effect()
downloadEpisodes$ = this.actions$.ofType( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE )
.pipe(
  map( ( action: episodeActions.DownloadEpisodes ) => action.payload ),
  switchMap( ( episode ) => {
    return this.episodesService
      .download( episode ) // -> download the media file as blobl
      .pipe(
          map( event => this.episodesService.getHttpProgress( event ) ), // => report download progress
          tap( message => {
            console.log( message );

          } ),
          // switchMap( response => new episodeActions.DownloadProgressEpisodes( response ) // => doesn't work cause its not iterable accoring to typescript.
          last(), // => emit last (completed) message to caller
          switchMap( response => {
            return this.episodesService.downloadSuccess( response ) // => process response blob
            .pipe(
              tap( response  => console.log('--->', response )),
              map( response => new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesSuccess( response ) ),
              catchError( error => of (new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesFail( error ) ) )
            )
          })
      )
  } )
);
```

This will report the following in my console:

```
Downloading file
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 7% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 11% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 15% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 18% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 26% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 30% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 44% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 48% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 70% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 74% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 File is 100% downloaded.
episodes.effect.ts:57 HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200,             statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/episodes/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.s…ple-videos.com%2Faudio%2Fmp3%2Fcrowd-cheering.mp3", ok: true, …}
```

**What do I want to change?**

Well, the `tap message` under the `getHttpProgress` function is called as many times until the upload is done. Then the `last()` call forwards the `httpResponse` to the next `switchMap`.

What I would like to achieve is to dispatch an action `new episodeActions.DownloadProgressEpisodes( message )` during the Download progress (multiple times) to store the download progress within the episode (call the reducer to update the episode entity).

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to dispatch multiple `DownloadProgressEpisodes` actions during the `download` process without breaking or the last `switchMap` that calls the `this.episodesService.downloadSuccess( response )`. 
I tried to add a action call after the `tap`, before the `last` call as it seemed to be an `Iterator`. However, it didn't dispatch those actions, nothing showed up in my redux devTool. 
When I dispatch the `DownloadProgressEpisode` from my service within the `getHttpProgress` call, It works but I am not sure if that is the proper way.

In the end I want to see the following in my redux devTool:

```
[Podcast] Download Episode;
[Podcast] Download Episode Progress; // payload 0%
[Podcast] Download Episode Progress; // payload 10%
...etc
[Podcast] Download Episode Progress; // payload 100%
[Podcast] Download Episode Success;
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Or alternatively, should I use different effects for the Download, which calls an effect for the DownloadProgress which repeats itself until finished and then call and effect for DownloadSuccess?

Answer (score 2):

I would split this effect in several smaller ones. Right now you're doing several things in the same effect: download, update progress and process the result. You can try to create an effect for each of them.

Download the episode:

```
@Effect()
downloadEpisode$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE),
  switchMap(({ payload }) => this.episodesService
      .download(payload).pipe(
         map(response => new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesSuccess(response)),
         catchError(err => of(new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesFail(error))),
      )
  )
)
```

Catch the download success action and process it:

```
@Effect()
processEpisode$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE_SUCESS),
  switchMap(({ payload }) => this.episodesService
      .downloadSuccess(payload).pipe(
         map(response => new episodeActions.ProcessEpisodesSuccess(response)),
         catchError(err => of(new episodeActions.ProcessEpisodesFail(error))),
      )
  )
)
```

And about showing/updating the progress:

```
@Effect()
updateProgress$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE),
  switchMap(({ payload }) => this.episodesService
      .getHttpProgress(payload).pipe(
         map(res => new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesProgress(res)),
      )
  )
)
```

This way of showing the progress assumes that *getHttpProgress* method will return a new observable each time a new episode is downloaded. We listed for the action that notifies the download was started and then we switch map to the output of getHttpProgress.

Comment: I did occur to me to do that but I was wondering if that would create to many effects. I read some opinions about relying to much on Effects and how it becomes to abstract. But in this case, there are 3 separate actions with reducers, so it make sense to use separate Effects for them, yes.

Comment: Is there a preference for `downloadEpisodes$ = this.actions$.pipe( ofType( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE ),` or `this.actions$.ofType( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE ).pipe` or is it all the same? I know `actions$` offers an `ofType` operator out of the box.

Comment: also, the response of the `this.episodesService.download` is of the type `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` . Only when HttpEvenType is 4, will there be a response that can be send to ProcessEpisodeSuccess.

Comment: So I think in the first DOWNLOAD_EPISODE effect I have to test the response (HttpEvent) for its type and based on that dispatch a PROGRESS or SUCCESS action. I will have a play.

Comment: There is an ofType method on actions but as far as I know it will be removed in favor of the operator ofType to be used inside the pipe method.

Comment: I did not test the above code, so treat it as a direction in which I would go :) If needed you can use map to change from HttpEvent to something that you need and use filter to remove the events that you don't want to send to process.

Comment: About the number of effects, I think of them the same as functions, would rather have several of that each do a single well defined thing than a larger one that does everything.

Comment: Your last suggestion about the updating of the progress: the payload coming from DOWNLOAD_EPISODE is of type Episode and not HttpEvent or HttpResponse. The result of the episodeService.download is a stream of HttpEvents and finally a response. So I feel like in the first effect, I would have to filter the Event out and either dispatch a ProgressUpdate or dispatch a Success. The DOwNLOAD_EPISODE action will never receive anything else then a Episode payload so I can't use that one for progress.

Comment: I will create another question with my new solution, if you would be willing to have a look. It's much better but I am still missing some understanding of how to split a stream and handle 2 different cases without breaking the stream for the rest of the consumer. My example will make that clear:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056685/ngrx-effect-for-downloading-media-file-and-dispatching-progress-how-to-deal-wit

Comment: this doesn't make sense to me - how can the second effect for DOWNLOAD_EPISODE get an event? how is this connected to the http response?