# NgRX Effect for downloading media file and dispatching progress; how to deal with the stream and throttling

Tags: angular6, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am struggling a bit with understanding and applying @Effects for my episode Download option. I got some help in another question and this is my latest concoction.

Quick overview: User clicks download which dispatches a `DOWNLOAD_EPISODE` action which is captured in the first Effect. The download call returns a stream of HttpEvents and a final HttpResponse.

During the `event.type === 3` I want to report download progress. When `event.type === 4` the body has arrived and I can call the success which for example can create a Blob.

Service `episodesService`:

```
download( episode: Episode ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {

  // const url = encodeURIComponent( episode.url.url );
  const url = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sample-videos.com%2Faudio%2Fmp3%2Fcrowd-cheering.mp3';
  const req = new HttpRequest( 'GET', 'http://localhost:3000/episodes/' + url, {
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'blob'
  } );
  return this.http.request( req );
}

downloadSuccess( response: any ): Observable<any> {
  console.log( 'calling download success', response );
  if ( response.body ) {
    var blob = new Blob( [ response.body ], { type: response.body.type } );
    console.log( 'blob', blob );
  }
  return of( { status: 'done' } );
}

getHttpProgress( event: HttpEvent<any> | HttpResponse<Blob> ): Observable<DownloadProgress> {

  switch ( event.type ) {
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      const progress = Math.round( 100 * event.loaded / event.total );
      return of( { ...event, progress } );

    case HttpEventType.Response:
      const { body, type } = event;
      return of( { body, type, progress: 100 } );

    default:
      return of( { ...event, progress: 0 } );
  }
}
```

The effects:

```
@Effect()
downloadEpisode$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<episodeActions.DownloadEpisodes>( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE ),
  switchMap( ( { payload } ) => this.episodesService.download( payload )
    .pipe(
      switchMap( (response: HttpEvent<any> | HttpResponse<any>) => this.episodesService.getHttpProgress( response ) ), //merge in the progress
      map( ( response: fromServices.DownloadProgress ) => {

        // update the progress in the episode
        //
        if ( response.type <= 3 ) {
          return new episodeActions.DownloadProgressEpisodes( { ...payload, download: {
            progress: response.progress
          } }  );

        // pass the Blob on the download response
        //
        } else if ( response.type === 4 ){
          return new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesSuccess( response );
        }
      } ),
      catchError( error => of( new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesFail( error ) ) ),
    )
  )
)

@Effect( { dispatch: false } )
processDownloadEpisodeSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<any>( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE_SUCCESS ),
  switchMap( ( { payload } ) => this.episodesService
    .downloadSuccess( payload ).pipe(
      tap( response => console.log( 'response', payload,response ) ),

      //  catchError(err => of(new episodeActions.ProcessEpisodesFail(error))),
    )
  )
)
```

I am pretty happy with this solution, however i do not like the If ELSE clause in the MAP as part of the DOWNLOAD_EPISODE Effect.

Ideally I want to split the stream there, if type is 3 I want to go route A which always dispatches `episodeActions.DownloadProgressEpisodes` with an Episode payload.
Whenever it is type 4, the last emitted event, I want to got the B route in the stream and call `episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesSuccess` with the response body.

I tried to add more effects but I always end up in a situation the the result stream of the `this.episodesService.download` will either be a progress update OR a response body. For the progress update, I require the Episode record to be able to call the reducer and update the Episode's progress.

I tried to use things as setting  `filter( response => response.type === 4 )` after the `DownloadProgressEpisodes` but before `DownloadEpisodesSuccess` hoping it would allow for an iteration before the filter to deal with the progress and then filter the rest through to the Success Action. 
I then learned that is not how streams work.

I also tried `last()` which did work but it didn't let me dispatch the Response Actions (the console log did work), but only the DownloadEpisodesSuccess action after the `last()` would be dispatched.

So, if it is possible to split the stream and deal with `event.type 3` differently then `event.type 4` I  would be interested in that.

*****UPDATE*******

I want to keep the original question, however I did run into a throttling requirement because I was dispatching a lot of actions for large files.
I tried the `throttle` operator but that would suppress emits but could also suppress the last emit with the response body. I tried splitting it with `partition` but I don't think that is possible. After a light bulb moment I decided to create 2 effects for `DOWNLOAD_EPISODE`, one which only captures all `event.type === 3` and throttles it and another effect that uses the `last` operator and only deals with `event.type === 4`.

See code:

```
  @Effect( )
  downloadEpisode$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<episodeActions.DownloadEpisodes>( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE ),
    switchMap( ( { payload } ) => this.episodesService.download( payload )
      .pipe(
        switchMap( (response: HttpEvent<any> | HttpResponse<any>) => this.episodesService.getHttpProgress( response ) ),
        throttleTime( 500 ),
        map( ( response: fromServices.DownloadProgress ) => {
          console.log('Type 3', response);
          // update the progress in the episode
          if ( response.type <= 3) {
            return new episodeActions.DownloadProgressEpisodes( { ...payload, download: {
              progress: response.progress
            } }  );
          }
        } ),
        catchError( error => of( new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesFail( error ) ) ),
      )
    )
  )

  @Effect( )
  downloadEpisodeLast$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<episodeActions.DownloadEpisodes>( episodeActions.DOWNLOAD_EPISODE ),
    switchMap( ( { payload } ) => this.episodesService.download( payload )
      .pipe(
        switchMap( (response: HttpEvent<any> | HttpResponse<any>) => this.episodesService.getHttpProgress( response ) ),
        last(),
        map( ( response: fromServices.DownloadProgress ) => {
          console.log('Type 4', response);
          if ( response.type === 4 ){
            return new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesSuccess( response, { ...payload, download: {
              progress: response.progress
            } } );
          }
        } ),

        catchError( error => of( new episodeActions.DownloadEpisodesFail( error ) ) ),
      )
    )
  )
```

What do you think, is this the best solution? Type 3 and 4 are split and I can throttle it.

*update2:
It does create an issue where the `Progress Action` with progress 97% can be triggered after the `Download Success` action with progress 100%.
Every time I run into a new challenge...

`SampleTime(500)` seems to work, since it doesnt seem to throw a Type 3 event after the Type 4 event came in.

*update3: I just found out that I am calling `Download` twice now in the effect, sigh. I am back at square one trying to throttle the HttpEvent stream coming from episodeService.download.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you don't want to have `if else` statement, you'll have to create  different effects.

In the current one you'll dispatch a new action, e.g. `DownloadEpisodeProgess`, with the type in the payload.
You will then create two effects that listens to this action and filter them accordingly via the type, one effect will be used to dispatch `DownloadProgressEpisodes`, the other one for `DownloadEpisodesSuccess`.

Another possible solution would be the [partition operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html), but I haven't used it in combination with NgRx Effects.

It is also good to keep in mind that for each subscription you make, there will be a performance cost, personally I don't really mind the `if else` statement.

Comment: I looked at the Partition operator too. Not sure if it works for NGRX, I tried and failed. But I can try again. I also don't mind the IF ELSE, I just want to throttle the amount of Actions dispatched for the Event Type 3.